DAC freq LOST and signal in osciloscop is unstable, used STM32 NUCLEOF334R8
sorry if I always ask.
If I have code like the one below with mapping the goal is to produce a 200hz signal on the oscilloscope. But why is the value of 'hasil' always the same as the value of uint16_t output_end = 2000;
and if I have got the frequency I want, the signal on the oscilloscope will sometimes disappear when I turn the potentiometer. is there a loop or wrong code in my code? please help. and I've read about ARR, well ARR produces a value that corresponds to the 'hasil' in the watch window, can anyone explain simply what it is. I've studied but I can't conclude it.
`#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */


//DAC
#define BUFFER_SIZE 225;
uint32_t WaveLUT [] = {
        2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048,2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048,
        2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048,2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 
        2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048,2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048,
      2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048,2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048,
        2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048,2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 
        2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048,2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048,
    2048, 2149, 2250, 2350, 2450, 2549, 2646, 2742, 2837, 2929, 3020, 3108, 3193, 3275, 3355,
    3431, 3504, 3574, 3639, 3701, 3759, 3812, 3861, 3906, 3946, 3982, 4013, 4039, 4060, 4076,
    4087, 4094, 4095, 4091, 4082, 4069, 4050, 4026, 3998, 3965, 3927, 3884, 3837, 3786, 3730,
    3671, 3607, 3539, 3468, 3394, 3316, 3235, 3151, 3064, 2975, 2883, 2790, 2695, 2598, 2500,
    2400, 2300, 2199, 2098, 1997, 1896, 1795, 1695, 1595, 1497, 1400, 1305, 1212, 1120, 1031,
    944, 860, 779, 701, 627, 556, 488, 424, 365, 309, 258, 211, 168, 130, 97,
    69, 45, 26, 13, 4, 0, 1, 8, 19, 35, 56, 82, 113, 149, 189,
    234, 283, 336, 394, 456, 521, 591, 664, 740, 820, 902, 987, 1075, 1166, 1258,
    1353, 1449, 1546, 1645, 1745, 1845, 1946, 1950, 1965, 1975, 1990, 1999, 2010,2022, 2047
};
#define ARRAY_SIZE 4
uint32_t AD_RES[ARRAY_SIZE];

//MAPP
//OUTPUT = DAC
//INPUT = ADC
uint16_t input_start = 0;
uint16_t input_end = 4095;
uint16_t output_start = 100;
uint16_t output_end = 2000;
uint16_t input ;
uint16_t i;
uint16_t hasil;
uint16_t y;
uint16_t x;

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;

DAC_HandleTypeDef hdac1;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_dac1_ch1;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim2;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

//ADC
uint16_t i = 0;
ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef ADC_CH_Cfg = {0};
uint32_t ADC_Channels[4] = {ADC_CHANNEL_6, ADC_CHANNEL_7, ADC_CHANNEL_8, ADC_CHANNEL_9};
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_DAC1_Init(void);

/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_DAC1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

        
    //ADC
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_3);
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_4);
    ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef ADC_CH_Cfg = {0};
    ADC_CH_Cfg.Rank =  ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
  ADC_CH_Cfg.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_1CYCLE_5;
    
    //DAC
    HAL_DAC_Start_DMA(&hdac1, DAC_CHANNEL_1, (uint32_t*)Wave_LUT, 225, DAC_ALIGN_12B_R);
    HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim2);

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
        
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
            //ADC
            ADC_CH_Cfg.Channel = ADC_Channels[i];       
      HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &ADC_CH_Cfg); 
      HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);                         
      if(HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, HAL_MAX_DELAY) == HAL_OK) 
                {
          AD_RES[i] = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
        }
         HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc1);
    }
            input = AD_RES[0]; 
            //output = output_start + ((output_end - output_start) * (input - input_start)) / (input_end - input_start);    
             hasil = (output_end - output_start) / (input_end - input_start) * (input - input_start) + output_start;
            __HAL_TIM_SET_AUTORELOAD(&htim2, hasil);    
            HAL_Delay(500);
            y = hasil;
            x = input;
    }

  /* USER CODE END 3 */
        
}`

I have tried and it produces an unstable signal and the value of 'hasil' follows the start output.

Welcome to SO. I cannot see anything that might create any output in your code. But it is rather clear, why hasil never changes: hasil = (output_end - output_start) / (input_end - input_start) * (input - input_start) + output_start; This is done using integer division. This is same as 1900/4096*input + output start which again is same as 0*input+output_start which is output_start. You must either rearrange to first multiple before you divide (keep integer ranges in mind, you might need to use a larger type) or use floating point arithmetics (which might be rather expensive)

@Gerhardh float is not a problem usung this MCU as it has FPU

I have already been able to produce the output value 'hasil,' but now my problem is that the output on the oscilloscope, the signal, sometimes disappears. When this happens, the CNT value increases significantly to 5-7 million, whereas when the signal is generated normally (according to the desired signal), the CNT value is only below 500. Can someone explain what influence the CNT has? I also want to ask if there is a parameter that accurately represents the frequency output observed on the oscilloscope in Keil? Please help me, this is very important. @0

I’m really out of ideas on how to deal with CNT. Do you have any articles/websites that could help me?

You didn't show us how you initialise the timer or the DAC or the ADC.

htim2.Instance = TIM2;
htim2.Init.Prescaler = 100;
htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
htim2.Init.Period = 0;
htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
@pmacfarlane

Please add all relevant code into the question, not in comments. And also put it in correct place to make a MCVE

Please update your question to include how you calculate hasil now. Add it as an additional code snippet, don't invalidate the old one. Can you be sure that you cannot get some overflow during your calculation that might end up with a negative value being used for your timer?

To separate your input and output and potential issues with both, you could use a loop over the whole allowed range for hasil and see, what you get as output signal. If that is OK, then you seem to have an issue with ADC or with calculation of hasil.
